# Running multiple JUnit5 test cases without dependencies

Tags: junit5

I'm wondering how I can execute some single file or entity that understands that I want to run a specified lists of JUnit 5 cases NOW?

I know that additions to JUnit5 are coming that are analagous to test suites but they clearly aren't available now and it's probably overoptimistic to expect them in the very near future. I've accumulated several tests now with several more to come and it's getting tedious to have to launch each independently and this will only get worse as the number of tests increases. Is there any code I can write today to automate running multiple tests in one go? That will tide me over until the upcoming code is available. :-)

I don't need anything fancy, just a way to provide a list of JUnit5 Test Cases that I want run in a single go. The tests don't have to run in a specified sequence and I'm happy to hard-code the names in a list of some kind; I don't need a GUI to make it all elegant because I can wait for that.

I'm using Eclipse 2018-19 on Windows 10 as my IDE but if I need to open a command prompt or use some different tool to launch my tests, I can live with that for now.

I've been trying to cobble something together on my own but it seems to be beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Have you considered making use of tags and tag expressions for selecting the tests you want to run? Filtering by tagging is already supported in Eclipse _Run Configurations_. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering

Comment: @SamBrannen - Sorry for the delay in replying; it's been a crazy week. I don't think I'm making myself clear yet. I can't run any JUnit5 Test Suites in any way, shape or form. I can run JUnit5 Test Cases without difficulty but I can't figure out how to make Eclipse run two or three or a dozen JUnit5 Test Cases in one go. If you or anyone else could enlighten me on how to do THAT, I'd be grateful :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the CLI options

```
  -c, --select-class=CLASS   Select a class for test discovery.
                             This option can be repeated.
  -m, --select-method=NAME   Select a method for test discovery.
                             This option can be repeated.
```

of the `ConsoleLauncher` either programmatically or via the standalone JAR as described here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

Here is a modified Gradle [code snippet](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/documentation/documentation.gradle.kts#L22-L35) that selects 3 test cases from the JUnit 5 User-Guide project:

```
val consoleLauncherTest by tasks.creating(JavaExec::class) {
    dependsOn("testClasses")
    val reportsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results")
    outputs.dir(reportsDir)
    classpath(sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath)
    main = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher"

    // "select all classes available" via args("--scan-classpath") or
    // supply a set of classes via "--select-class":

    args("--select-class", "example.JUnit4Tests")
    args("--select-class", "example.FirstJUnit5Tests")
    args("--select-class", "example.DisplayNameGeneratorDemo")

    args("--details", "tree")
    args("--include-classname", ".*Tests")
    args("--include-classname", ".*Demo")
    args("--exclude-tag", "exclude")
    args("--reports-dir", reportsDir)
    systemProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This looks like it will meet my needs but, honestly, my knowledge of Gradle is very limited and despite reading the section of the manual in your link, I'm not sure what I need to do. At the very least, it looks like I need the jar file but I'm not sure where to get it. (The link to the jar doesn't seem to have a download link and I have no knowledge of Maven at all. Also, I'm not clear where the snippet you've provided should be written (or rather my code modeled on your snippet should be written). I assume it goes in a file somewhere. Can you clarify?